# Imposible acceder a una variable asignada en un subscribe

Tags: angular, oauth2, auth, cognito

Estoy realizado una autentificación mediante la librería [oidc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-auth-oidc-client/v/10.0.10), realiza el acceso al login externo sin ningún problema y me devuelve al root de mi aplicación.

El problema viene aquí:
Cuando realizo la subscripción a los observables justo después del login no puedo acceder a ningún dato, a no ser que realice una recarga de la página, que entonces si puedo obtener los datos. He realizado la configuración tal cual aparece en la información de la librería.

Pongo el código en concreto justo despues del login:

**app.component.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.oidcSecurityService.getIsAuthorized().subscribe((auth) => {
    this.isAuthenticated = auth;
  });

  this.oidcSecurityService.getUserData().subscribe((userData) => {
    if (userData) {
      this.userDataLoadedGet = userData;
      console.log(userData) //Aqui tengo datos
    }
  });

  console.log(this.userDataLoadedGet); //Aqui no
}
```

He observado que carga 3 veces y a la 3 si coge los datos, pero no sé cómo indicarle a angular que espere para obtener los datos antes de continuar.

Comment: Tema de asincronía, que deberías manejar con un `observable`. ¿Dónde vas a usar ese dato? La idea es usarlo cuando esté disponible. Tal como lo tienes no funciona porque intentas acceder inmediatamente al valor.

Comment: La intención es cuando esté disponible, pasar el dato a un servicio y poder acceder a el cuando lo necesite en otros componentes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se puede solucionar el problema de asincronismo con la utilización de `pipe()` y `tap()`.

EL codigo quedaría de esta manera:

```
let $oidcSecurityService = of({ userData: "usuario" }); // Simula respuesta del servicio correspondiente
let userDataLoadedGet: any;
let isAuthenticated: any;

function obs() {
  $oidcSecurityService.subscribe(auth => {
    isAuthenticated = auth;
  });

  $oidcSecurityService
    .pipe(
      tap(userData => {
        userDataLoadedGet = userData;
      })
    )
    .subscribe();
    console.log(userDataLoadedGet); // output: {userData: "usuario"}
}
obs();
console.log(userDataLoadedGet); // output: {userData: "usuario"}
```

El operador `tap()` puede leer el flujo de datos y ejecutar acciones ajenas al mismo. En este caso lo utilizamos para asignar el valor de `userDataLoadedGet`.

Acá te dejo el [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-vinr1k?file=index.ts) de StackBlitz para que pruebes vos mismo esta solución.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías utilizar los ciclos de vida de Angular para poder utilizarlo. Es decir, si haces las operaciones que quieras en un ciclo de vida posteior al ngOnInit, por ejemplo

```
class MyComponent implements AfterViewInit, AfterContentInit {
  ngAfterContentInit() {
    // Llamadas a tu servicio utilizando la variable this.userDataLoadedGet que ya deberia tener datos
   }
  ngAfterViewInit() {
   // Llamadas a tu servicio utilizando la variable this.userDataLoadedGet que ya deberia datos
   }
}
```

Creo que esta aproximación podría solucionar tu problema.